# Integral Form of the Remainder of the Taylor Series

Tags: calculus

If $g$ has 1 derivative on an open interval $I$ that contains the point $a$, then for each $x\in I$ the taylor polynomial gives $g(x)=g(a)+R(x)$ with $R(x)=\int_a^x g'(t)(a-t)^0\,dt$. My question is when $x=a$ is it we follow the convention that $(a-a)^0=1$ in $R(x)$, so that $R(a)=\int_a^a g'(t)(a-t)^0\,dt=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention throughout when working with power series is that when $(x-a)^k$ appears and it so happens that $x=a$ and $k=0$, the term is interpreted as $1$, yes. (Rationale: Certainly $(x-a)^0=1$ for all $x\ne a$, and power series certainly should be continuous on the interval of convergence.)

Comment: When $x=a$, is it we are not able to use the lagrange form of the remainder, $R(x)=\frac{g'(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$, where c is a point between x and a?

Comment: Well, at $a$ itself, there is no error, so remainder formulas would be silly :)